# Setting correct permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

First of all let me say that i am almost new to Linux so please be patient :)
I have an Ubuntu 14.0.4 running on my Systems.

What i am trying to do is:
On my system there are sabnzbd and plex running.
sabnzbd is running as root and plex has an own user (plex) with an own group (plex).

What i need is that the user plex, myuser and also sabnzbd (root) have read, write and execute permission at `/media` and also all subfolders and files.
I studied now a lot of stuff at the internet and tried my luck with `chmod`; `chown`; the `/etc/group` file; and many more but i am to stupid to get it to work.

Can someone tell me what i need?

Answer (score 1):

For a little more secure approach I'd recommend creating a group for those 3 users and then chown'ing the directory by the group.

```
1. sudo groupadd mygroup

2. sudo usermod -aG {group-name} username
```

In your case it'd be

```
sudo usermod -aG mygroup plex ; sudo usermod -aG mygroup root ; sudo usermod -aG mygroup myuser

3. chown -Rf :mygroup /media
```

Comment: Sound pretty good - thanks. Just one more thing. Under /media there i have an ntfs hdd mounted with the permission option at fstab. Can i somehow remove unneccessary permissions first because acl is active and i already messed up a bit :( or will chown remove everything anyway?

I tested now and "sudo useradd -G mygroup plex" will give me back something like this "useradd: User >>plex<< already exists" also for the other users.

Comment: Sorry i got the wrong command. Edited the answer accordingly. In case of the ntfs i think that the chown will edit the permissions anyway, but in case any problem arise don't hesitate to comment here

Comment: I did this now and rebooted my system. Access seems to be OK but i seem no to be a sudoer any more: myuser ist nicht in der sudoers-Datei.  Dieser Vorfall wird gemeldet. - myuser is not an member of the sudoers file. What to do?

Comment: Reboot to the recovery console and add your user back to sudo from there

on newer installations you will likely need to remount the root filesystem read-write first

# mount -o remount,rw / # usermod -aG sudo user # exit

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was not able to boot into recovery - my system is to fast :) But i did reinstall the system because a lot of stuff were messed up anyway. It now worked with the -aG comment thx. One more thing left - sabnzbd is running as root and moving files to /media/Store where i changed the permission as shown above. The new files to not take over the permission and belong to root:root and that a problem because i now cant change them (PS: The folder /media/Store is also shared with smaba) so it would be good that all permissions are myuser:mygroup and this also for new files.

Comment: Well that is due to the sabnzbd running as root. If you do not require to run it as such, then your problem is solved. I can't see any other way than this, but maybe a more experienced user would know. Only thing i can think of, that won't involve manually changing the permission is scheduling a script that does it to run every now and then.

Comment: I was worried that this would be the answer :). But i solved my issue now. I changed the primary group of myuser to the one i use for /media and changed the permission for every file sabnzbd need to the same like /media. And now everythings fine :) Thx a lot to you and thumbs up to the forum!

Comment: Thanks :) feel free to accept this as the answer if the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform this following command:

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media
```

where:

-Rf will force change the permissions recursively.

"777" will get for root, root group and others the permission for read, write and execute everything on the directory.

Comment: This **grants write privileges to everybody**, not just the 3 mentioned users, and may not be what OP wants or needs. It also makes all files executable, which may lead to confusion and even security problems.